# Запретить пересоздание фрагментов в BottomNavigationView с использованием NavigationGraph в Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view, navigation

У меня в приложении используется связка BottomNavView + NavGraph
Возникла такая проблема, что при переходе между фрагментами в BottomNavView, фрагменты пересоздаются.
Вопрос - как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Я как-то решал такую проблему через ViewPager. Само собой без navigation компонента. Возможно, Вам это подойдет